# How to configure domain name on school network

Tags: networking, dns, 8.04, hostname

I'm trying to set up my server (running Ubuntu server 8.04) on my university network so that I can access it from anywhere on campus. Last year I had it plugged into my router and set my router's domain like `network.myschool.edu` and hostname to `dlh`. This allowed me to access the router using `dlh.network.myschool.edu`, and I just used port-forwarding to access the server.

Now I'm just plugging the server in sans router and I'm trying to emulate the same setup. I have Avahi installed and I've tried setting my `/etc/hostname` to both `dlh` and `dlh.network.myschool.edu`. It doesn't seem to be working though when I try to `ping` from another computer.

Honestly though, I don't understand the whole domain/hostname thing very well and I'm not sure how this is done properly.

Comment: Talk to your helpdesk, or if you're lucky, to someone in the networking or sysadmin group.  They could tell you if DHCP was available, and if not, they could give you whatever other particulars you'd need.

Answer (score 3):

The school will have a fully resolved domain name of the nature “school.edu” and machines on that network will be resolved by the school DNS Server to be “server.school.edu”. This DNS Server will also, probably in cooperation with a DCHP server, allocate the machine an IP address.

For your machine to take part in this the school IT support department needs to make changes to there servers. If they cooperate and depending upon the setup they use your machine might become available on the local network and possibly on the internet with a fully resolved name.

Alternately, as you already had the machine set up at home you could leave it there and access it via the internet.

Or again, if you are willing to work with IP addresses you might get away with a standard DCHP configured machine on the local network and simply connect to the IP address.

Use ifconfig on the server to find its IP address then from another machine try pinging that address or connecting to a service on that machine.

Answer (score 1):

I would contact the network administrator of your school. Maybe they have changed some setup to provide additional security.